# Prevent injection via URL input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, unix

In my Rails controller, I take a URL that the user inputs and runs the system command `wget`:

```
system("wget #{url}")
```

I'm afraid that the user might put in something like `www.google.com && rm -rf .`, which would make the controller execute the command

```
system("wget www.google.com && rm -rf .")
```

which deletes everything. How should I prevent against this kind of attacks? I'm not sure what other things the user could put in to harm my system.

Comment: Isn't there a version of "system" that takes separate parameters for command and arguments?

Comment: @Thilo: yes [there is](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system). There are also Ruby replacements for `system('wget ...')` so you can bypass the shell and wget completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [this thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/196871):

You can avoid shell expansion by passing arguments to the script individually:

```
system("/bin/wget", params[:url])
```

Per the documentation on [Kernel#system](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system) this form does not invoke a shell. Constructs like `&&` are shell constructs, so if you use this form, then the param will be passed to `/bin/wget` literally as an argument.

That said, still be suspicious of input, sanitize where possible, and if feasible, run it as a non-privileged (or better yet, jailed) user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Chris! Is there any difference between using `system("/bin/wget", ...)` and `system("wget", ...)`?

Comment: No difference if wget is in your path. Don't assume that your search paths will be set for your Rails app, though.

Comment: /bin/wget is explicit so it is safer, wget depends on PATH variable settings.

Answer (score 2):

Joining commands together with `&&` (or `;`, or `|`) is a shell feature, not something that `wget` itself understands.  If you're using a function that passes a command line to a shell (such as the `system()` function in many languages), you're at risk.  If you execute the `wget` program directly (rather than executing a shell and giving it a command line), you won't be at risk of that particular attack.

However, the attacker could still do other things, like abuse `wget`'s `-O` option to overwrite files.  You'd be better off not using `wget` at all — if your goal is to download a file, why not just use an HTTP library to do it directly in your own program's code?

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is to just retrieve the content of the URL, it is better to completely avoid the use of 'system' or any other means of running a command on the server.

You can use an http client such as Httparty to fetch the URL content.

`response = HTTParty.get("#{url}")`